# Why is my if statement not working the way I expect?

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

I am trying to achieve the following: I ask my SQL database a query using `SELECT * FROM subjects`. After doing that I ask for the array using `mysqli_fetch_assoc`. Until that point all is fine. The problem now is that when I try to modify in each loop the value of $genero depending if it's 1 or 0. But the value of $genero never changes, it's always 1 and I am sure that the array is fetching 0 and 1. Any idea while the values of $genero are not changing through the loop?

```
while ($subject = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
if ($subject["sexo"] = 1) { 
    $genero = "<img src='images/hombre.png' />";
} else {
    $genero = "<img src='images/mujer.png' />";
}
    echo $genero;
}
```

Comment: Put 1 inside quotes, it might not be an integer coming from the database but inked be a string

Comment: @scrowler: PHP implicitly converts between the two.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your comparison operator is wrong. You're using `=` which is an *assignment* operator. In your example it will always be true. You need to use `==` which is a *comparison* operator.

```
if ($subject["sexo"] = 1) {
```

should be

```
if ($subject["sexo"] == 1) {
```

Comment: If you're talking about assignment in general then, no, it will not always be true. `$x = 0` does not evaluate to anything truthy.

Comment: I said "the expression". The right hand being the constant `1`. I agree the same is not true for _any_ expression, but it is true for _this_ one.

Comment: @John Code THANK YOU ¡¡¡¡ worked perfect. I am just starting php and I supose these is a rookie common mistake.

Answer (score 0):

In `if` statement you should use double equal sign: `if (a == b)`